# compilation java javax.el.ExpressionFactory

Tags: java, apache, compilation

i tried to compile a code, this class  compiled and i broke someth

I search impossible to find this method and which jar miss
    import javax.el.ExpressionFactory

```
org.apache.commons.jexl2.Expression e =    ExpressionFactory.newInstance().createExpression;
```

i tried to add commons-jexl_2.1.1.jar and i hava this error
    Multiple markers at this line
    - The method createExpression(String) is undefined for the type 
     ExpressionFactory

i tried grepcode but it seem not recognized createExpression

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: i forget this code

Comment: import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;